# At least 2 different letters in regex

Tags: regex

What regex checks if there are at least two different letters in a string?

For instance:

- aa -> Not match
- ab -> Match
- a -> Not match
- 012 -> Not match

Comment: By changing the wording and adding “abc” as a match you have substantially changed the question to the extent that valid answers given to the original question may now be invalid. Please revert your question and if necessary ask another new question to cater for the new problem.

Comment: It clearly said from the beginning at least two different letters, I'll revert anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "different" just means "separate" and you only want letters from the English alphabet, this should do the trick. The following regex will find match strings with **at least two** English letters:

```
.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*
```

- `.*` matches 0 or more of any character except a newline character
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches any character in English alphabet case-insensitively

If you want a regex that matches strings with at least two **different** English letters, this one satisfies that criteria:

```
.*([a-zA-Z])(?!\1).*([a-zA-Z]).*
```

- `(regex stuff)` creates a "capturing group" whose result is referenceable by later tokens
- `(?!\1)` is a *negative lookahead* that asserts no capturing group can match the result of the first capturing group
- `\1` is a *backreference* that matches the result of capturing group #1

You can test these here: https://www.regextester.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need exactly 2 chars, where the second is not the first:

```
^(.)(?!\1).$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/SSWTl6irUNwMCr).

Breakdown:

- `^` start
- `(.)` captures the first char as group 1
- `(?!\1)` a *negative look-ahead* that asserts the following character is not the same as the first character
- `.` a character
- `$` end

---

To restrict the match to only letters (upper or lower case):

```
^([a-zA-Z])(?!\1)[a-zA-Z]$
```

Comment: I'm looking for these two characters to be letters, how would you change it?

Comment: @DavidMasip please define what “letters” means. Uppercase? Lowercase? Either?

Comment: Both uppercase and lowercase